# Will a Microsoft Office Add-In developed in Visual Studio work for both a Windows and Mac (OS X) versions of MS Office?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, ms-office, add-in

I want to develop a Microsoft Office Word Add-In for Mac users. I would like to know if we create it using Visual Studio in Windows will it be compatible with the Mac version of Microsoft Office or is there a completely different way to develop for Mac?

Please provide links so that I can follow some guidelines. The http://msdn.microsoft.com/ site doesn't exactly speak of the platform compatibility of the Add-In.

Answer (score 1):

Office for Mac does not provide an API for add-ins and documentation for office automation on Mac OS X is rare.

However, you should be able to customize it using VBA solutions as described in this tutorial by Microsoft:

> **[Office for Mac: Automate tasks with Visual Basic macros](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/7/F/A7F9018D-3B23-4EDA-A554-A128C74C366C/Word%20or%20Excel%20Tutorial%20-%20Automate%20tasks%20with%20Visual%20Basic%20macros.pdf)**